# How disable LoadingBar of Quasar completely?

Tags: quasar-framework

Is it possible to disable the LoadingBar of Quasasr completely? It's loading with every AJAX request, but I have own solution for it.

Source:

https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/loading-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> WARNING
>
> When using the UMD version of Quasar, all components, directives and
>   plugins are installed by default. This includes LoadingBar. Should you
>   wish to disable it, specify loadingBar: { skipHijack: true } (which
>   turns off listening to Ajax traffic).

Link - https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/loading-bar#Installation

Set skipHijack to true for disabling QAjaxBar.